# c# display list of "friends" in facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

What would be the best method for a desktop app to logon to Facebook (using user inputed creditably) and list out all the friends w/ ID #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com). If you download the current release you will find a sample that will show you how to do what you are asking. However, one thing to note is that you cannot collect the user's username and password directly. You must use OAuth in order to authenticate the user. This is all show in the WinForms sample.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the API that facebook provides

you would first need to authenticate
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop

and then you would need to look at the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

to look up the friends (FriendList)